# Play application stops immediately when running with Intellij configuration

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

When running `sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8` compiling and running from terminal everything works perfectly well.
But when importing the project to IntelliJ, Adding a "Play 2 App" configuration, and running it, the program runs perfectly but stops immediately. Also, The play logo is shown twice.

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
[info] welcome to sbt 1.6.1 (Azul Systems, Inc. Java 11.0.13)
[info] loading settings for project play-scala-seed-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from /Users/idanahal/projects/scalaPlayTutorial/play-scala-seed/project
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info]   __              __
[info]   \ \     ____   / /____ _ __  __
[info]    \ \   / __ \ / // __ `// / / /
[info]    / /  / /_/ // // /_/ // /_/ /
[info]   /_/  / .___//_/ \__,_/ \__, /
[info]       /_/               /____/
[info] 
[info] Version 2.8.12 running Java 11.0.13
[info] 
[info] Play is run entirely by the community. If you want to keep using it please consider donating:
[info] https://www.playframework.com/sponsors
[info] 
[info]   __              __
[info]   \ \     ____   / /____ _ __  __
[info]    \ \   / __ \ / // __ `// / / /
[info]    / /  / /_/ // // /_/ // /_/ /
[info]   /_/  / .___//_/ \__,_/ \__, /
[info]       /_/               /____/
[info] 
[info] Version 2.8.12 running Java 11.0.13
[info] 
[info] Play is run entirely by the community. If you want to keep using it please consider donating:
[info] https://www.playframework.com/sponsors
[info] 

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

Server started, use Cmd+P to stop

[info] p.a.i.l.c.CoordinatedShutdownSupport - Starting synchronous coordinated shutdown with ServerStoppedReason reason and 35000 milliseconds timeout
[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Stopping Akka HTTP server...
[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Terminating server binding for /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Running provided shutdown stop hooks

[success] Total time: 3 s, completed 11 Jan 2022, 18:51:03

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I didn't do anything but it immediately starts to shut down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for me "Enable auto-reload" option in the configuration fixed the problem.

Comment: Newbie question: what configuration are you referring to? What file do I put "Enable auto-reload" in? Thanks.

Comment: Under "Edit Configurations" when the configuration is set to be 'Play 2 App'.

Comment: thank you! I had Community version, which doesn't support Play 2, so I was even able to create the configuration. Installed Ultimate and now things are working (with Enable auto-reload)

Answer (score 0):

you need to give run command like ~run

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables : autoReloadPlugins= true